# nested where clause i mysql giving sql grammmar exception

Tags: java, mysql

I need help with MySQL as I am new to it.

Basically for a selected date range i need the count of records where tracking number is present in a table called `UniwareReport` but airway bill no. is not present in `MisReport`

Below is what i attempted but i know that is not right.

```
select count (*) from UniwareReport
  where invoiceCreated >=:sDate
    and invoiceCreated <=:eDate
    and TrackingNumber NOT IN(select airwayBill from MisReport)


@Override
public Long getUniwareReportsCountInDateRange(String param) throws ParseException {
    String sDate = param;
    String eDate = param;
    //String oId = saleOrderNumber.trim();
    Query query;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    if (param.contains("-")) {
        String date[] = param.split("-");
        sDate = date[0];
        eDate = date[1];
    }
        query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
                "select count (*) from UniwareReport where invoiceCreated>=:sDate and invoiceCreated <=:eDate and (SELECT trackingNumber from UniwareReport where trackingNumber NOT IN(select airwayBill from MisReport))");
        Date startDate = DateUtils.addToDate(dateFormat.parse(sDate), Calendar.DATE, 0);
        Date endDate = DateUtils.addToDate(dateFormat.parse(eDate), Calendar.DATE, 1);
        query.setParameter("sDate", startDate);
        query.setParameter("eDate", endDate);
        //query.setParameter("oId", oId);
        return (Long) query.uniqueResult();

}
```

Comment: Please include the code that contains this SQL query.

Comment: And post all details of the error message.

Comment: <AST>:0:0: unexpected AST node: query.. this is the error

Answer (score 0):

You don't need another SELECT from UniwareReport inside your subquery. This should work:

```
select count (*) from UniwareReport
  where invoiceCreated >= :sDate
    and invoiceCreated <= :eDate
    and TrackingNumber NOT IN (select airwayBill from MisReport)
```